# Python 3.6: Append a 3D List

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, append

My Code:

```
Images = [Img1, Img2, Img3, Img4, Img5, Img6, Img7, Img8, Img9]
i = len(Images)
tmp_list=[[[0]*3]*ImgHeight]*ImgWidth

for i in range(i):
    for source_x in range(ImgWidth):
        for source_y in range(ImgHeight):
            tmp = Images[i].getpixel((source_x,source_y))
            for tmp1 in range(3):
                tmp_list[source_x][source_y][tmp1].insert(tmp[tmp1])
```

I want to save the color channel of each pixel in a separate list from each image in the list. For this I have a 3D list.
I got the error Message:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'

When I use

```
print(tmp_list[source_x][source_y][tmp1])
```

Output:

> [43, 23, 76, 24, 97,234, 243,21,23]

Comment: Please don't do this: `tmp_list=[[[0]*3]*ImgHeight]*ImgWidth` You're duplicating the reference.

Comment: Okay, what is your hint?
How can I make it better?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use `np.zeros` or `np.empty`. I assume your images are numpy arrays. In which case, you should explain what you are trying to do at a higher level, and possibly some sample input and output for  (say) 3x3 images. There should be an easier way to solve this.

Comment: Similar way, `[[[a for a in range(N)] for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(N)]`

Comment: Yes, my images are numpy arrays. I would like to apply a median filter to the images. Given several images, a temporal median filter takes a list of pixel channel values at each coordinate and calculates the median.

Comment: What are you trying to do? In the last line of code, `tmp_list[source_x][source_y][tmp1]` should be a number, not a list, so you cannot use `insert` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use something like this:

```
from itertools import product

ImgHeight = list(range(8))
ImgWidth = list(range(8))
# ^ product on this will return generator of tuples with all x,y combinations
# which you will see bellow 

# place your images into dictionary as keys with dictionaries as value
images_source = {
    Img1: {}
}

for image in images_source:
    for x, y in product(ImgHeight, ImgWidth):
        r, g, b = image.getpixel((x, y))
        images_source[image][x, y] = [r, g, b]
```

As you can see - it's better readable than multiple nested loops.
I used random to generate values, and here what i've got:

```
{'Img1': {(0, 0): [191, 82, 190],
          (0, 1): [122, 119, 164],
          (0, 2): [218, 225, 146],
          (0, 3): [217, 34, 128],
          (0, 4): [0, 135, 114],
          (0, 5): [193, 224, 4],
          (0, 6): [186, 210, 186],
          (0, 7): [232, 149, 158],
          (1, 0): [51, 113, 191],
          (1, 1): [177, 175, 245],
          (1, 2): [5, 219, 54],
          (1, 3): [230, 165, 241],
          (1, 4): [41, 48, 39],
          (1, 5): [16, 16, 188],
          (1, 6): [62, 133, 242],
          (1, 7): [255, 237, 221],
          (2, 0): [98, 159, 60],
          (2, 1): [135, 132, 209],
          (2, 2): [248, 171, 34],
          (2, 3): [35, 155, 166],
          (2, 4): [237, 63, 245],
          (2, 5): [184, 189, 164],
          (2, 6): [194, 68, 148],
          (2, 7): [68, 34, 58],
          (3, 0): [247, 128, 219],
          (3, 1): [30, 142, 60],
          (3, 2): [77, 66, 157],
          (3, 3): [53, 164, 51],
          (3, 4): [77, 52, 145],
          (3, 5): [169, 113, 59],
          (3, 6): [232, 204, 70],
          (3, 7): [120, 40, 128],
          (4, 0): [219, 156, 67],
          (4, 1): [128, 168, 120],
          (4, 2): [188, 8, 71],
          (4, 3): [233, 213, 91],
          (4, 4): [63, 34, 223],
          (4, 5): [145, 137, 84],
          (4, 6): [112, 193, 111],
          (4, 7): [50, 143, 19],
          (5, 0): [5, 119, 61],
          (5, 1): [168, 84, 28],
          (5, 2): [211, 14, 73],
          (5, 3): [251, 155, 64],
          (5, 4): [199, 211, 213],
          (5, 5): [135, 41, 121],
          (5, 6): [163, 3, 57],
          (5, 7): [2, 50, 167],
          (6, 0): [66, 20, 212],
          (6, 1): [55, 0, 229],
          (6, 2): [76, 61, 47],
          (6, 3): [241, 234, 249],
          (6, 4): [203, 7, 130],
          (6, 5): [216, 188, 202],
          (6, 6): [58, 31, 136],
          (6, 7): [191, 248, 197],
          (7, 0): [109, 132, 16],
          (7, 1): [198, 176, 36],
          (7, 2): [138, 98, 215],
          (7, 3): [255, 38, 206],
          (7, 4): [73, 59, 202],
          (7, 5): [192, 61, 89],
          (7, 6): [148, 30, 233],
          (7, 7): [68, 126, 154]}}
```

Without storing coordinates in dictionary with values zipped:

```
from itertools import product

ImgHeight = list(range(3))
ImgWidth = list(range(3))

images_source = {
    'Img1': [],
    'Img2': [],
}

for image in images_source:
    for x, y in product(ImgHeight, ImgWidth):
        r, g, b = image.getpixel((x, y))
        images_source[image].append([r, g, b])

zipped_values = list(zip(*images_source.values()))
```

And data would be :

```
# zipped_values                      # x y
[([216, 123, 197], [178, 214, 35]),  # 0 0
 ([2, 115, 179], [216, 188, 103]),   # 0 1
 ([102, 62, 255], [113, 69, 218]),   # 0 2
 ([188, 31, 59], [160, 117, 154]),   # 1 0
 ([255, 115, 10], [114, 142, 238]),  # 1 1
 ([64, 176, 189], [228, 10, 85]),    # 1 2
 ([121, 76, 202], [53, 217, 149]),   # 2 0
 ([114, 159, 18], [9, 202, 139]),    # 2 1
 ([146, 178, 59], [5, 216, 172])]    # 2 2

# images_source
{'Img1': [[178, 214, 35],            # 0 0
          [216, 188, 103],           # 0 1
          [113, 69, 218],            # 0 2
          [160, 117, 154],           # 1 0
          [114, 142, 238],           # 1 1
          [228, 10, 85],             # 1 2
          [53, 217, 149],            # 2 0
          [9, 202, 139],             # 2 1
          [5, 216, 172]],            # 2 2

 'Img2': [[216, 123, 197],           # 0 0
          [2, 115, 179],             # 0 1
          [102, 62, 255],            # 0 2
          [188, 31, 59],             # 1 0
          [255, 115, 10],            # 1 1
          [64, 176, 189],            # 1 2
          [121, 76, 202],            # 2 0
          [114, 159, 18],            # 2 1
          [146, 178, 59]]}           # 2 2
```

So, you could iterate over zipped_values with:

```
for i, coordinate in enumerate(product(ImgHeight, ImgWidth)):
    colors = zipped_values[i]
    x, y = coordinate
    # do your stuff here
    # average example:
    # average_rgb = [sum(i)//len(colors) for i in zip(*colors)]
```

Average rgb per coordinate with previous data:

```
[197, 168, 116] # 0 0
[109, 151, 141] # 0 1
[107, 65, 236]  # 0 2
[174, 74, 106]  # 1 0
[184, 128, 124] # 1 1
[146, 93, 137]  # 1 2
[87, 146, 175]  # 2 0
[61, 180, 78]   # 2 1
[75, 197, 115]  # 2 2
```

Also, you can create another dictionary and append each pixel color to it directly:

```
from itertools import product

ImgHeight = list(range(3))
ImgWidth = list(range(3))

images_source = [Img1, Img2]
new_image = {}

for image in images_source:
    for x, y in product(ImgHeight, ImgWidth):
        r, g, b = image.getpixel((x, y))
        new_image.setdefault((x,y), [])
        new_image[x,y].append([r, g, b])

for coordinate, colors in new_image.items():
    x, y = coordinate
    # do your stuff here
    # average example:
    # average_rgb = [sum(i)//len(colors) for i in zip(*colors)]
```

new_image structure:

```
{(0, 0): [([178, 214, 35], [216, 123, 197])],
 (0, 1): [([216, 188, 103], [2, 115, 179])],
 (0, 2): [([113, 69, 218], [102, 62, 255])],
 (1, 0): [([160, 117, 154], [188, 31, 59])],
 (1, 1): [([114, 142, 238], [255, 115, 10])],
 (1, 2): [([228, 10, 85], [64, 176, 189])],
 (2, 0): [([53, 217, 149], [121, 76, 202])],
 (2, 1): [([9, 202, 139], [114, 159, 18])],
 (2, 2): [([5, 216, 172], [146, 178, 59])]}
```

Comment: Yes, that's true my code looks a little bit unreadable. I want to overlay the nine different Images and get the median color from each pixel.
At the end its only one Image. This removes outliers and can act to subtract unwanted elements from an image.

Comment: @JonasDeichelmann check another example in my answer, maybe it would fits your requirements better

Answer (score 1):

I changed the loop Structur and changed the List.
My Code:

```
ImgWidth, ImgHeight = Img1.size
canvas = Image.new("RGB", (ImgWidth, ImgHeight), "white")
Images = [Img1, Img2, Img3, Img4, Img5, Img6, Img7, Img8, Img9]
i = len(Images)

for source_x in range(ImgWidth):
    for source_y in range(ImgHeight):
        tmpRGBList = [0,0,0]
        for tmpChannel in range(3):
            tmpColorList = []
            for tmp_int in range(i):
                tmpPixel = Images[tmp_int].getpixel((source_x,source_y))
                tmpColorList.append(tmpPixel[tmpChannel])
                if tmp_int == 8:
                    tmpColorList=sorted(tmpColorList)
                    tmpRGBList[tmpChannel] = tmpColorList[4]
        canvas.putpixel((source_x,source_y), (tmpRGBList[0], tmpRGBList[1], tmpRGBList[2]))
canvas.save("final.png")
```

This works now.
Thanks for your support!